# JQuery Click Event is called for the Wrong Class after adding and removing classes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm building a Django Application and stuck at the JQuery issue. When I click on the Paragraph with class ***'select'*** it triggers the jQuery click event, the issue is when I change the class name from 'select' to ***'selected'*** using JQuery, it still triggers the 'select' class click event whereas it is supposed to not be called after removing the 'select' class. Here is the sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".select").on('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass('dont_select')
  $(this).removeClass('select');
  alert("Click event called")
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p class='select'>Change Class Using Jquery</p>



</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please explain the solution?

Comment: You need to remove the event listener; changing the class doesn't automatically removes the event listener. Alternate option is to check which class `p` element has and take appropriate action based on the class `p` element has.

Comment: That's the expected behavior. When you attach the event, removing a class won't remove the attached event automatically. You could attach the click event to the closest common parent element of `.select`  elements, and use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) to attach the events.

Comment: Event listeners get added to the element(s) that match that selector at the time. The element still exists even when you remove the class

Comment: Exactly, `$(".select")` simply grabs a list of elements that match at the time the command runs; the selection doesn't extend into the future.

Comment: Unless dynamic elements will be added, you can do this: https://jsfiddle.net/d96pucvh/

Comment: @Teemu solution worked. Event Delegation fixed the issue. The updated JQuery script is: 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.select', function(){
  $(this).addClass('dont_select')
  $(this).removeClass('select');
  alert("Click event called")
  });
});
</script>

Thank you everyone for helping. You guys are great :D

Comment: You can also simply remove it as follow, in your script instead of adding/removing class: ```$(this).off('click');```